# Dumping an SVN branch fails, empty Dump

Tags: svn, svndump, svndumpfilter, teamforge

EDIT: This one has been worked around. What REALLY helped me out here, though, was the tool [svnsanitizer](https://github.com/dsuni/svndumpsanitizer). Basically the code was extremely badly dislocated, with dependencies all over the entire repository. This tool took a full SVN dump as a file (DO NOT PIPE IT!) and sanitized all the linked folders, resulting in a bunch of folders completing the branch. I REALLY don't know why my users have over 2000 moved folders in a single branch... But, that's life.

Anyway, case closed. Better than nothing I guess. Hope this helps anyone struggling with a similar case!

---

This one's a head scratcher to me, since I barely work with SVN:

I have to dump a branch from a fairly large SVN repository managed by a Teamforge instance (the SVN part seems to be fairly standard). The full dump works fine, but filtering out the wanted branch fails, as there is no content in the dump file. Any branch I try fails. However, there's definitely code in there when I browse the repository through the web interface, code files and everything.

These are the commands I used:

```
svnadmin dump /svnroot/foo > big-svn.dump

svndumpfilter include /branch/foo --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs < big-svn.dump > foo.dump
```

foo.dump is always 195 bytes in size and contains something like this:

```
SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2

UUID: some-generic-UUID-stuff

Revision-number: 0

Prop-content-length: 56

Content-length: 56

K 8

svn:date

V 27

2013-01-29T13:00:15.018082Z

PROPS-END
```

Things I tried so far to resolve this without success:

- Change Arguments and options around, remove options, use --patterns
- Changing paths to filter out, like hit and miss
- Dumping a different branch as a test, also empty
- Using svndumpfilter2 and 3
- grep on the big dump for the path, it returns a few results, but no code around the lines it appeared on.

How can I dump this specific branch without the entire rest of this fairly large repository?